# Program not saving inputted entries? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I am supposed to make a class AddressBook containing a class called Person. My program almost, works, except when I add a person, it doesn't remember it in the next iteration of the Command menu and Display All turns up "There are 0 people in your address book." What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  

using namespace std;

class AddressBook {

public:
    class Person
    {
    public:
        char firstName[15];
        char lastName[15];
        char personID[15];
    };

    Person entries[100];

    unsigned int total;

    AddressBook()
    {
        total = 0;
    }

    void AddPerson()
    {
        cout << "This is entry number " << (total + 1) << " in your address book. " << endl;

        cout << "What shall we put for the first and last name? Limit both to under 15 characters. Example: Bob Smith" << endl;
        cin >> entries[total].firstName >> entries[total].lastName;

        cout << "What is " << entries[total].firstName << " " << entries[total].lastName << "'s ID code?" << endl;
        cin >> entries[total].personID;

        ++total;
        cout << "..." << endl << "Successfully Added." << endl;
    };

    void DisplayPerson(int i)
    {
        cout << "Entry " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cout << "FIRST NAME: " << entries[i].firstName << endl;
        cout << "LAST NAME: " << entries[i].lastName << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << entries[i].personID << endl;
    };

    void DisplayEveryone()
    {
        cout << "You have " << total << " People in your address book." << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
            DisplayPerson(i);
    };


    void SearchPerson()
    {
        char lastname[32];
        cout << "Please enter the last name of the person you wish to find." << endl;
        cin >> lastname;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(lastname, entries[i].lastName) == 0)
            {
                cout << "Person Found. " << endl;
                DisplayPerson(i);
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    };




};


int main() {
    char command;
    bool Exit = false;

    while (Exit == false)
    {
        AddressBook Address_Book;
        cout << "---------------COMMANDS---------------" << endl;
        cout << "A: Add Person To Address Book" << endl;
        cout << "S: Search for Person in Address Book" << endl;
        cout << "D: Display Everyone In Address Book" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Type the letter of your command: ";
        cin >> command;
        cout << endl;
        switch (command) {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            Address_Book.AddPerson();
            break;
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            Address_Book.SearchPerson();
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            Address_Book.DisplayEveryone();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "That is not a valid command. Closing Address Book." << endl;

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: A question for the OP -- What would happen if I have more than 100 entries?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you create a new address book in each iteration of the while loop and throw it away at the end of the iteration:

This

```
AddressBook Address_Book;
```

creates a new address book that is "thrown away" when you reach the end of its scope (ie. the end of the loop).

In reality, do you buy a new address book whenever you want to make new entry? No. You first buy the book and then (possibly in a while loop) you add entries. Move the above line outside of the loop.

Comment: For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the declaration of your address book.

Change it to the following:

```
AddressBook Address_Book;

while (Exit == false) {
    //Ask for input and respond.
}
```

In your version `Address_Book` is declared at the start of the `while` loop. This means that every time an iteration of the loop completes and execution returns to the start of the block, a new local `Address_Book` object is created that has no knowledge of the previous objects data.